# How to use sphinx with nested directories when not all directories contain python files

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

This question seems to be fairly common, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368523/how-to-generate-sphinx-docks-in-nested-directory#48370291) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64936509/sphinx-nested-inlude-across-nested-directories), but their solutions did not work for me.

The directory structure looks like this:

```
└──faulty_meters_study
    └── __init__.py
    └── utils.py
    └── anomaly_detection.py
    └── visuals.py
    └── anomalous_kwh_detection
        └── __init__.py
        └── general_anomalies.py
        └── slowing_down.py
    └── data 
        └── x_data.npy
        └── y_data.npy
    └── docs
        └── conf.py
        └── index.rst
        └── etc
```

`data` does not contain any files that need to be documented, but `anomalous_kwh_detection` does. I run sphinx using the following commands

```
sphinx-quickstart
sphinx-apidoc -o . ..
make html
```

My `conf.py` file looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
project = 'a'
copyright = '2021, b'
author = 'b'
release = '0.0.1'
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc','sphinx.ext.napoleon']
templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']
html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

and my `index.rst` file looks like:

```
.. a documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Thu Aug 19 21:54:31 2021.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to a's documentation!
=============================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 6
   :caption: Contents:

   modules

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

When I run `make html`, I get the error: `WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'anomaly_detection' from module 'faulty_meters_study'; the following exception was raised: No module named 'faulty_meters_study'`  for all modules.

That error usually happens when the path to the directory is not specified in `conf.py`, but I did specify it. I'd appreciate if someone can help me out finding what is wrong and how to make sphinx works.

As a smaller additional question, is there a problem if a script looks like this:

```
a = 3+1

def function1(arg1):
    """
    Documentation
    """
    return arg1*2

p = a+7
```

meaning a script that has functions, but also has lines of code that get executed and are not documented.

Comment: If `faulty_meters_study` is the top-level package, then you need `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))`.

Comment: Is this solved by my previous comment? It seems like a duplicate of several similar questions, such as https://stackoverflow.com/q/62340756/407651 and 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/52648002/407651

Comment: Yes, it was solved by your previous comment. And it is a duplicate.